# Остаток от деления для разных типов

Tags: c++, mod

Почему остаток от деления operator% работает только с int%int либо double%double и т.д. Я думал что тип неявно преобразуется до большего, однако я не понимаю почему компилятор этого не делает?

Не нашел разумного ответа. Могу конечно сам переписать остаток от деления, почему так реализовано, может есть какие то подземные камни?

Comment: в с++ делать double%double  нельзя. С Java не путаете? Это же взятие остатка от целочисленного деления. Для какого типа ещё Вы ожидаете такое?

Comment: 1. с++ в какой-то степени пошёл от ассемблера (пусть даже от си  - не играет большой роли). Большинство операций с числами имеют прямые аналоги с ассемблером ( то же а+=b имеет аналог add eax,ebx;). У ЦП операции остатка для double не было, не следил появилась такая операция сейчас или нет. Не помню такой. 2. Видимо на момент создания си, остаток от double-double - никто не считал. И точность double была низкой. Из подводных камней - низкая точность ирациональное число, infininity даст "странный" остаток. Возможно это вторая причина по которой это неполучило распространение.